# Verilog Syntax error - parameter

Tags: verilog, fpga

```
  parameter tDDKHMH =  (tDQBit < 580) ? 150 : (tDQBit < 688) ? 150 : (tDQBit < 791) ? 245;   

`ifdef USE_EXACT_VALUES
  parameter tCISKEW   =  (tDQBit < 580) ?  93 : (tDQBit < 688) ? 112 : (tDQBit < 791) ? 125;  
  parameter tDDKHAS   =  (tDQBit < 580) ? 410 : (tDQBit < 688) ? 495 : (tDQBit < 791) ? 606 ;
```

## parameter tDDKXDEYE =  (tDQBit < 580) ? 350 : (tDQBit < 688) ? 400 : (tDQBit < 791) ? 500 ;

ERROR, Syntax error near ( ; ).
ERROR, Syntax error near ( ; ).
ERROR, Syntax error near ( ; ).
ERROR, Syntax error near ( ; ).

Comment: The final else expression for tDQBit greater equal 790 is missing.

Answer (score 0):

There are three points to note here:

1. Please make sure that tDQBit is a constant. Parameter's value can not be 
   evaluated dynamically, i.e., tDQBit must not be a signal/wire/register.
2. The conditional expression must have both true and false part. The last 
   conditional expression in your code does not have the false part of it.
   (tDQBit < 791) ? 500; which is not correct.
3. Please use brackets where ever possible to avoid the confusion.

I have assumed that the false part of (tDQBit < 791) is 600. Hence it can be written be in this way:

parameter tDDKXDEYE = (tDQBit < 580) ? 350 : ((tDQBit < 688) ? 400 : ((tDQBit < 791) ? 500 : 600));